# Information about 'ventoy' application

Tags: applications

i recently installed 'ventoy' application from google store, but after i run the application it ask me for internet connexion i was think it is used offline, so why it ask for internet connexion and is it safe to give it access to internet? Thanks for your help.
Best wiches.

N.B: link for the application it is used for making a usb key bootable with '.iso' distribution.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixapplications.ventoy_app&gl=US

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! It might help if you'd **[edit]** your question to include a link to that app. With almost 3 million apps at Play, it'sotherwise hard to guess which one you mean – especially as you do not even mention what the app might be for. Looking at [the only candidate I could find](https://www.appbrain.com/app/ventoy-bootable-usb-%5Bno-root%5D/com.mixapplications.ventoy_app), it seems to use Firebase and Google Ads (both are requiring network but should not be needed for the functionality the user wants). "Overloaded with ads" a review says…

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, yes it is this app, when i run it the application show a message "must connect to internet", i don't know why it ask for a connexion, i know it use ads but most applications use ads but don't ask for connexion, thanks for your help. Best wishes

Comment: I see no reason why the app would need Internet to fulfil its purpose – provided the purpose is the same as that of the Ventoy application for Linux (just preparing the stick). So if the app does not work offline, I'd address the author for the reason and ask how to use that app on a device that cannot connect to any network anymore;)